# MySQL server not starting because of MySQL56 service

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am unable to start MySQL56 service once i stopped it. Previously my MySQL 6.0 workbench was working all fine but once i stopped this service(MySQL56) from services in task manager, I am not able to start my MySQL server as it says

```
"Status check of service 'MySQL56' returned stopped"
```

and I am not able to find any way to start it again. When I click enable the service for MySQL56 in task manager it says

```
 "The service can not be started either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it".
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the mysql logs?

Comment: Can you start the service from the service manager?

Comment: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?169,570663,570898 might be related and may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Type **"services"** in the **Start** search bar in windows.

Hit Enter.

Now in the services list scroll down for **"MySQL56"**.

Right click on it & choose **Start**. (This will start it.)

To make this automatic:

Again Right click on **"MySQL56"**.

Choose **Properties**

Now opt for **"Automatic"**.

If the above service is not running, then it also creates problem in **Workbench**. ("Cannot Connect to Database Server" error)

Comment: How come I can't find MySQL56 on my Services list?

Comment: It would have different name due to different version, but it will surely starts with MySQL. Example: MySQLxx.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. That will open the Task Manager.

Then go to the *Services* tab.

At the left column, you can see the names of the services.

Search for the service you need (for me it is MYSQL57) and right click on it and choose start.